# How to press link or button only when it is available on page else go to next step?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to "Sign In" link only when it is available on page. If it is not available on page means user is logged in already.

How can I do it using Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

For links, you can use the below selenium IDE command.

```
Command : waitForText
Target  : link=textpresent on the link
Value   : text that should be present on the link
```